# Fastest way to access data

Tags: javascript, data-access

I have a large text file, file1.txt(contains many numbers) and I need to access the data inside it would it faster to use an array of the numbers and use array indexing or use an object or whatever accesses the data the fastest.
The file is like so,

```
    6.9883,
    7.673454,
    2.563745,
    etc...
```

Comment: How do you want to reference your data? What kind of queries will you perform against that data? There's no way to answer your question without knowing how it will get used. Every data structure has it's use and must be chosen depending on use cases. Voting to close until you add additionnal details.

Comment: How do you get the file into JS?

Comment: -plalx it is stored as a variable and used in an if statement when it evaluates to true

Comment: -rudie it is stored as a variable(of some sort)

Comment: Just so you know, in order to reply to someone, you should use `@user3184807`

Comment: I know but its faster not to

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way to access those data is to load them into an array and access them using an array index, even in earlier versions of Internet Explorer, which IMO was amazingly slow in dealing with any JavaScript arrays.

Comment: what about using an object

Comment: I find it interesting that I've gotten at least one downvote here, but no alternative views have been offered and no explanation for the downvote(s)...